# How to fetch data Array in Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I call API on my react JS app  :

```
result = fetch('http://localhost:5000/cities')

result.then(function(response) {
 console.log(response.json());
})
```

Then output log :

```
Promise
  __proto__ : Promise
  [[PromiseStatus]] : "resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]] : Array[5]
     0: Object
     1: Object
     2: Object
     3: Object
     4: Object
      length: 5
     __proto__: Array[0]
```

How do I fetch data on Array ?

I need get city name list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `response.json()` returns a promise that resolves to the parsed JSON.

You can simply write

```
result.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Awsome... Thanks Amir!